# How can I prove that the closure of a set in a metric space is the set of all limits of sequences in that set?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and let $A \subsetneqq X$. Let $E$ be the set of all $p$ in $X$ for which there exists a sequence $(p_n)$ in $A$ such that $ p = \lim\limits_{n\to \infty}p_n$.

Show that $E$ is the closure of $A$.

Comment: I don't have an inclination of how to start a proof for this. Ann outline would be awesome. I know the textbook definition of closure, but I do not have an intuition on how to use the definition to help.

Comment: @johndoe: You have $p ∈ \overline{A}$ and you want to show that there is some sequence in $A$ converging to $p$. The key property here is that metric spaces are first countable meaning that each point has countable local basis which is nice for making a sequence.

Comment: @johndoe: you may not realize that there are *multiple* textbook definitions of closure. We will be more likely to be helpful if you tell us which one you're using.

Answer (score 2):

You have two sets, $\operatorname{cl}A$ and $L$, the set of points that are limits of sequences in $A$, and you’re to show that they’re equal. One of the most common ways to show that two sets are equal is to show that each is a subset of the other. In this case that means showing that $\operatorname{cl}A\subseteq L$ and $L\subseteq\operatorname{cl}A$. And one of the most common ways to show that $C\subseteq D$ is to show that if $x\in C$, then $x\in D$. Thus, to show that $\operatorname{cl}A\subseteq L$, you should try letting $x$ be an arbitrary point of $\operatorname{cl}A$ and showing that there is necessarily a sequence in $A$ that converges to $x$. To show that $L\subseteq\operatorname{cl}A$, you should try letting $x$ be an arbitrary point of $L$ and show that this forces $x$ to be in the closure of $A$. I’ll get you started on both. The second is a little simpler.

- Let $x\in L$. Then by definition of $L$ there is a sequence $\langle p_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ in $A$ that converges to $x$. Let $\epsilon>0$ be arbitrary; can you use that sequence to prove that $B(x,\epsilon)\cap A\ne\varnothing$? (Here $B(x,\epsilon)$ is the open ball of radius $\epsilon$ centred at $x$.)
- Let $x\in\operatorname{cl}A$. For each $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ let $p_n\in B\left(x,\frac1n\right)\cap A$. (How do you know that there is such a point?) Can you where to go from here?

Comment: Hi. For the first part, is the intersection nonempty because the sequence in A is within any given epsilon distance of the limit point? For the second part, i am still a little lost. If you choose an arbitrary x is in the cl A, then how do you know it will be within epsilon distance of L. I am studying this on my own time, and i still dont have an intuition for these things

Comment: @johndoe: What you have to show in the second part is that if $x\in\operatorname{cl}A$, then $x$ is actually **in** $L$, meaning that there is a sequence in $A$ converging to $x$. If your $L$ was a typo for $A$, and you’re wondering how I know that $B\left(x,\frac1n\right)\cap A=\ne\varnothing$, remember that $x\in\operatorname{cl}A$ if and only if every open nbhd of $x$ contains a point of $A$.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT:**

A point $p \in X$ is in closure of $A$ if and only if for every neighbourhood $U$ of $p$, there exists a point $p_{U} \in A \cap U$.

Now since you are in metric space, you have a local base consisting of balls of radius $1/n$.

So, you can take $U = B(p,1/n)$.